# nginx 1.21.1 - spaces in request line - 400 Bad Request

Tags: nginx

Since version 1.21.1 nginx now returns a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error when there is a space in the request url.

From the nginx official [changelog](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES):

```
*) Change: now nginx always returns an error if spaces or control
   characters are used in the request line.
```

My server is still receiving some requests with spaces in the GET query string from some  older Android devices. I know that spaces in the url need to be encoded, but I have a few special cases where this is not possible right now.

Is there any option to turn off this new behaviour without having to revert to version 1.21.0?